# How to update global variable in Postman?

Tags: postman

I have a test which Posts some items
e.g.
POST:item : 1
POST:item : 2 and so on

and now in 1st Post request, I am trying to set a global variable in pre-request-script

`postman.setGlobalVariable("item", 1);`

and use this variable in the body
e.g

```
 "item": "{{item}}",
```

it work.
Now in 2nd Post request, I wanted to increment global variable, in pre-request-script

```
item=item+1;
postman.setGlobalVariable("item", item);
```

and in body same as above.
but its give following error

> There was an error in evaluating the Pre-request script: item is not
>   defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

postman.setGlobalVariable("item", Number(postman.getGlobalVariable("item"))+1);

Comment: this is outdated

Answer (score 9):

With the current version of Postman (6.2.x), you can set the variables in the Tests tab like

**Global Variables**

```
pm.globals.set("variable_key", "variable_value");
```

**Environment Variables**

```
pm.environment.set("variable_key", "variable_value");
```

To update the answer, it will be

```
pm.globals.set("item", Number(postman.getGlobalVariable("item"))+1);
```